# How to add csv data config in switch controller

Tags: jmeter

I want to randomly select 1 csv data config out of 9 in jmeter. I am using switch controller and added 9 csv data configs. But it is not selecting any one. I am getting data from all csv's.

Answer (score 0):

Create 9 variables in "User Defined Variables" and assign different file names for each variable (file1=file1.csv,file2-file2.csv,.....).

Create another "User Defined Variables" and use ${__RandomFromMultipleVars(file1|file2|file3|file4|file5|file6|file7|file8|file9)} to select any of the above variables randomly and use it in CSV data set config.

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9JEs.png)

[User defined variables 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFu8g.png)

[User defined variables 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjwJz.png)

[CSV data set config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv4gw.png)

[Results Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyGcb.png)